# How can I update screen values when I change the screen

Tags: python, kivy

I have a script in python and a kivy file with different screens. In screen 1 i introduce some information in a `TextInput` and when I change to the following screen (screen 2) I want to recover the values of the variable I introduce in `TextInput` of screen 1. I have problem to update value in function `__init__` of screen 2.

I don't know which is the best way to update values automatically.

```
class PantallaDos(Screen):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(PantallaDos, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        softinput_mode = 'below_target'
        Window.softinput_mode = softinput_mode

        self.ids['pol'].text = 'verdadero'
```

Kivy kv.file

```
<PantallaDos>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10
        spacing: 3
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0.15,0.14,0.14
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

....

        SLabel:
            id: pol
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.width, 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the shared data in the ScreenManager class, or App class forexample.
Or just access it directly in kv.
Here is an example, where you just use the id of the textinput, in kv, to set the label text in the other screen.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""

<Manager>:
    Screen:
        name: 'first'
        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: ti
                text: 'type something'
            Button:
                text:'go to other'
                on_press: app.sm.current = 'other'

    Screen:
        name: 'other'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: ti.text
            Button:
                text:'go to first'
                on_press: app.sm.current = 'first'

""")


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ClassApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.sm = Manager()
        return self.sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClassApp().run()
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot.